# Sql developer importing excel date in 12 hour formay

Tags: excel, date, import, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to import date column using SQL developer but it's always changing to 12 hour format on import i.e if time is 18:00 it's importing as 6.

Could you please help with this ? I tried changing the nls in preferences and also tried changing system data format but it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you want to be sure to make use of the Date Format entry on the wizard for the column you're reading from Excel during the Import wizard.

[image]

For your date, make sure you are using HH24 and not HH to represent the time.

A date in the Excel file:
[image]

Then as it's imported using a format date of '`MM/DD/RR HH24:MI`'

```
 18-06-1987 14:00:00
```

Comment: I'm using the same thing but seems the date is set during the import step i.e set to 2 instead of 14 hours, and changing it at the format step doesn't make much difference

Comment: @Shivam Update your question to include the TABLE definition and a sample of the EXACT data you're trying to import..CSV format would suffice